# Multi-threaded lock-free doubly linked list using free-list

Tags: c, multithreading, atomic, lock-free, compare-and-swap

I want a concurrent data structure that works like a singly linked list and only needs `append` and `remove_iterator` operations. In the end, one thread will `iterate` all nodes. From my research, I got an [implementation](https://github.com/gavra0/ConcLinkedList) that has `append`, `remove_value` and `search_value` operations with singly-linked lists. It is based on [Harris' algorithm](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall05/G22.2631-001/lists.slides2.pdf).

The problem is that in Harris' algorithm, `remove_value` only marks a node logically deleted, without actually delete it. `search_value` actually do the chores of removing logically deleted nodes. But since I don't have a `search` operation for my use case. I keep a long list with lots of logically deleted nodes. It is just not efficient for speed in multi-threading, because all the work of deleting nodes is put on the `iterate` operation within a single thread.

I wonder if there are any other **implementations that fit my needs**. Any recommendation is appreciated.

If **not**, I wonder if I can implement something for this special case using a [free-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list) with a lock-free stack implementation. In this case, an `append` operation becomes `pop` free-list, either put value to the node or append to our list if empty. A `remove_iterator` operation becomes mark the node logically removed, and `push` the node pointer to free-list.

I think lock-free stack if fairly easy to implement. I can use some [implementations](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2014/09/02/) online.

---

Some code in mind.

```
struct node_t {
    node_t *next;
    int deleted;
    val_t val;
};
struct list_t {
    node_t *head;
};
struct fl_node_t {
    node_t *padding_1;
    int padding_2;
    fl_node_t *next; // assume sizeof(val_t) >= sizeof(fl_node_t*);
};

struct free_list_t {
    fl_node_t * head;
};
```

```
void append(val_t val) {
    fl_node_t *fl_head;
    fl_node_t *fl_next;
    node_t *head;
    node_t *new_node
    /* Try insert to one of the node in free-list */
    if (free_list.head) {
        do {
            fl_head = free_list.head;
            next = fl_head->next;
        } while(!CAS(&free_list.head, fl_head, fl_next)); 
        if (fl_head) {
           fl_head->node->val = val; 
           return;
        }
    }
    /* Append to head */
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    new_node.val = val;
    new_node.deleted = 0;
    do {
        head = list.head;
        new_node.next = head;
    } while(!CAS(&list.head, head, new_node));

}
```

```
void remove(node_t *node) {
    fl_node_t *fl_node;
    fl_node_t *fl_head;

    /* Mark logically deleted */
    node->deleted = 1;
    fl_node = (fl_node_t*) node;

    /* Add to free-list */
    do {
        fl_head = free_list.head;
        fl_node->next =fl_head;
    } while(!CAS(&free_list.head, fl_head, fl_node)); 
}
```

---

Comment: What is the condition that imposes a need for lock-free?

Comment: Many threads working on the same data structure at the same time. Non lock-free works. I have a global lock for the list. The performance isn't great. I can definitely switch to a fine-grained locking for each node. However, it may impose a lot of memory overhead. A mutex is 0x40 bytes while my val_t is just 0x8 bytes. And the list is huge.

Comment: What about having N locks for some small fixed N, and randomly coloring nodes? I'm not sure if you can make a safe lock-order protocol with this, but it sounds plausible.

Comment: Do you mean the following. Instead of one list. I can use N lists and N locks. And randomly add the value to one of the lists. When updating, just lock the correct lock. In this way, there is no lock-order needed. I think I could try a variation that uses a new list and lock whenever N values are added.

Comment: That's not what I meant, and wouldn't work if your lists are storing an ordering between nodes, which I assumed they would since that's what linked lists are usually used for. But if it does work for you, great! That avoids the lock order difficulties entirely.

Comment: I see what you mean. Assume a doubly-linked list. You need to acquire 3 locks in order, prev, cur, next, for example. I can hardly figure out their colors. And what if the 3 has the same color.

Comment: If they have the same color, you're lucky - you only have to get one lock. The problem is that you can't observe the adjacent nodes until you have the initial one locked. And one node's color and adjacent colors might be 0,1,2 while another node's color and adjacent colors might be 2,0,1, so the adjacency order doesn't give a lock order.

Comment: I think you might be able to solve this by coloring links rather than nodes (having both nodes store the color of the link between them). Then each node would have to store 2 colors (one for link to prev, one for link to next).

Comment: Sounds like you might be talking about _hand-over-hand locking_. People have written about that. Check Google.

Comment: It sounds like you need three operations: forward iteration, append, and remove_iterator.  Are some of these only performed by one thread?  For example do you have one thread modifying and one thread reading?  Or one writing and many reading?  Knowing restrictions like these would help in terms of finding a solution.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yes, The `forward_iteration` is only executed in one thread. `append` and `remove_iterator` are executed in multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: How do you get the iterator to remove if you don't iterate in that thread?  Do you only ever remove the head?

Comment: I store the pointer/iterator to the node somewhere else. Every node in the list is possibly removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found gavra0's implementation on [github](https://github.com/gavra0/ConcLinkedList/). With a modification by adding a free-list (using lock-free stack implementation), I got some working code.

The repository is https://github.com/buszk/ConcLinkedList. And the implementation is in this [link](https://github.com/buszk/ConcLinkedList/blob/dev/src/linkedlist-custom/linkedlist.h) in the `dev` branch.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to Lock free and wait free data structures, rather than try to reinvent the wheel or fix something and spend ages trying to prove that it's right, **use a proven existing implementation where possible**.

Lock free implementations are notoriously hard to get right and difficult to prove right.  What is right on one CPU architecture, may be wrong on another.

In practice, where we've had to use them for performance reasons they can go and go, and then one day blow up.  We've had good success with implementations adapted from here

http://www.1024cores.net

He also has references to other libraries and provides good insight into concurrent programming.  Well worth a read.

Comment: Really appreciate your advice. As you stated, it is very hard to prove the correctness of lock-free algorithm. There is no implementation that fits my needs. Therefore, I used two well-studied implementations: T. Harris' singly linked list and lock-free stack. Though I don't have a formal written proof for my data structure, it is passing the test cases implemented by @gavra0 on github. I am fairly confident with the implementation I've done.